# How to sumarize corectly datetime (difference between end_date and begin_date) - mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, difference

I'm using in mysql. I've created table "Sikcness" and I've added one record:

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+
| Id_SICK|ID_WORKER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE            |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+------------+---------+
| 1      |   1     |2019-03-18 07:00:00  |2019-03-20 15:00:00  |  
+--------+---------+--------+------------+----------+----------+
```

Then i'd like to sumerize in time (Time difference between End_date column and begin_date column) by the command:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Sickness.END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(Sickness.BEGIN_DATE))) AS 'SICKNESS TIME' FROM Sickness WHERE ID_WORKER = 1
```

But i have only that result (which is incorrect):

```
SICKNESS TIME
08:00:00
```

That command should count it like this:

```
+---------+-------------+--------+----------+
| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE            |
+---------+----------+------------+---------+
|2019-03-18 07:00:00  |2019-03-18 15:00:00  |  
+--------+------------+----------+----------+  
|2019-03-19 07:00:00  |2019-03-19 15:00:00  |  
+--------+------------+----------+----------+  
|2019-03-20 07:00:00  |2019-03-20 15:00:00  |  
+--------+------------+----------+----------+
```

Then it would be correct:

```
SICKNESS TIME
24:00:00
```

What kind of mysql query should i write? Any ideas? Greets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference in hours you should multiply by difference in days:

```
mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM((DATEDIFF(end_date, begin_date) + 1) * (TIME_TO_SEC(END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(BEGIN_DATE)))) AS 'SICKNESS TIME' FROM Sickness WHERE ID_WORKER = 1;
+---------------+
| SICKNESS TIME |
+---------------+
| 24:00:00      |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Another query with TIME_FORMAT:

```
mysql> select time_format(SUM((datediff(end_date, begin_date) + 1) * (time(end_date) - time(begin_date))), '%H:%i:%s') as 'SICKNESS TIME' from Sickness where id_worker = 1;
+---------------+
| SICKNESS TIME |
+---------------+
| 24:00:00      |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can try this query on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6ba89/2/0)

Comment: I've made with this command but it have shown too much = 56:00:00. I need the query which counts like this where i described at the top

Comment: No difference. I'm sorry :(

Comment: Is '24:00:00' preferred result?

Comment: simpler [`TIME_FORMAT(SUM(TIMEDIFF(END_DATE, BEGIN_DATE)),'%T')`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bf639/2)

Comment: Yes i'ts the most helpful for me. Thank you very much for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to calculate it like this:

1. Number of hours on the first day of sickness
2. Number of hours on last day of sickness
3. Number of days in sickness multiplied by 8 (i.e. number of working hours)

Once done, you need to add these up to get the result, e.g.

```
SELECT
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, begin_date, CONCAT(DATE(begin_date), ' 15:00:00')) +
(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, begin_date, end_date) - 1) * 8 +
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, CONCAT(DATE(end_date), ' 07:00:00'), end_date) AS time 
FROM test
WHERE worker = 1;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/405efa9/16/0)**.